# Python help needed. Whats the best way to gather data from a spreadsheet into an array that can hold strings and numbers

Tags: python, arrays, excel, string, pandas

Would like to import data from spreadsheet, currently using pyxl. Whats the best way to read the excel data and insert it into an 2D array. Is it Numpy? Pandas? Lists? I am new and I am struggling how to insert into a variable like so:

MaterialData[y, x] = data from spreadsheet where y is the row and x the column.
I am using a for loop to go through the cells but I am cant find the way to put the data into an array.

```
for i in range(1, rows+1):
    for j in range(1, 6):
        col = sh.cell(i, j)
        col1 = col.value
        materialsList[i,j] = col1
```

The last line obviously is in error, but that's what i want to do, if it makes sense! The excel file is a list of materials where each column has a different prices, and depending on what the user selects in the program, that price is shown. (well that's a very simplified version of what i want to achieve). Part of the data in this array will be displayed on a listbox using tkinter, depending on flags set by the user.

Any advice welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work on spreadsheets, using pandas is a better option than using numpy array.
Pandas DataFrame is a 2D numpy array under the hood. But it’s good to have column headers,index, etc,so that we  can change those things on the fly
Pandas handle heterogeneous data very nicely, with numbers of inbuilt functions which will make the job easy.

ways to convert the pandas data-frame to its Numpy-array representation.

```
 spreadsheet_np_array = df.as_matrix(columns=None)
 OR
 spreadsheet_np_array = df.values
 OR
 spreadsheet_np_array=np.asarray(your_data_frame_here).
```

[pandas reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: This seems to work well in the sense that the array IS created, will work around with it a bit and get back to you. Appreciate your help thank!

Answer (score 0):

pandas is a very good library the allows developers work with excel files.
try the following code in the same location with the excel file.

```
    import pandas as pd
    file_x = 'Scores.xlsx'
    scores = pd.read_excel(file_x)
    scores_dict = scores.to_dict()
    rows = []
    for row in scores_dict.values():
        cols = []
        for col in row.values():
            cols.append(col)
        rows.append(cols)
    print(rows)
```

that should solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code. I ran it, but It gave me a long single list of all items in the excel sheet, not an array. What I am after is the ability to peek a value using an array sort of function. I need to know what value (column) of a specific row contains.

Comment: the final result is going to be a list of lists which is equivalent to a two dimensional array. each inner list represents the rows and any of them can be accessed using its index.e.g rows[1] will give you the second row while rows[1][0] will return the first column in the second row. hope that helps